# Changing colors in style.css is not applying on WP theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

For changing colors in some part of a WordPress theme, I've changed the background or color property of those elements (found using inspect in chrome) in style.css. But it is not changing in the theme.

I also tried making child theme of the theme. But no result.

For example, the style.css contains -

```
#header .nav_bg {
    background: #7bae39;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I've changed it to -

```
#header .nav_bg {
    background: #109DE4;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

N.B: I've tried with SiteOrigin Custom CSS plugins, and it works with that. But I want to do it by changing CSS.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use higher selector, element that contains that div or use 
!Important before ;
Just add code to custome css in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

If the same selector works with other plugins you might wanna try a few test to try to see what's going on.

1. Go the page and look for the style you just added on the
   inspector. You can see by selecting the element if it is getting
   applied and overridden by other css rule. In that case you can
   update the rule to be more specific.
2. If the css is not showing up at all, you can try:

   - clearing your browser cache
   - check the page on incognito / a different browser

Hope it helps,

Comment: Glad to know! So for clarification purposes, what happens it that the browser caches the resources for better performance. That means it temporary saves all of the files so it doesn't have to load them again. That includes CSS. Your update was working fine but your browser was cached with a previous version of the site you were working on. Always check incognito mode / a different browser and always give the 'Clear browser cache' a shot before thinking some styling update is not working :)